# Why I can't access to module page in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I can not access the module page in OpenCart 2.3. 
Texts of error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant VERSION - assumed 'VERSION' in
>   /home/flower/mywebsite.com/system/storage/modification/system/engine/model.php
>   on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Proxy in
>   /home/flower/mywebsite.com/system/engine/proxy.php on line 2

this module, designed to transfer data from 1C to OpenCart, the error began to appear after the cache module was installed

```
model.php:

1 <?php
2 
3 $GLOBALS['jetcache_opencart_core_start'] = microtime(true);
4 if (!defined('SC_VERSION')) define('SC_VERSION', (int) substr(str_replace('.', '', VERSION), 0, 2));
5 if (SC_VERSION < 22  && !class_exists('Proxy')) {
6    if (function_exists('modification')) {
7      require_once(modification(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/jetcache/proxy.php'));
8   } else {
9      require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/jetcache/proxy.php');
10   }
11
12}
proxy.php:

1 <?php
2 
3 class  Proxy  {
4
5   public function __get($key) {
6
7      return $this->{$key};
8
9   }
```

Comment: Well the problems are described by the error log pretty good. You have an undefined constant (which is bad but not fatal to the application) and you try to redeclare a class. This happens mostly by importing / requiring the same file twice. Use `require_once` / `include_once` to prevent such issues.

Comment: In log file - nothing,

Comment: You got an error log (at least you posted error messages in your question). Somehow the class `Proxy` got redeclared in the file `/home/flower/mywebsite.com/system/engine/proxy.php` This means, there is already a class called proxy. Please post the first 5 lines of the mentioned file.

Comment: I was added code

Comment: Well, as the message says `VERSION` is undefined in `model.php:4`. You might want to check, which file is responsible for defining it.
The fatal error becomes clear here: You have defined a class called Proxy in `proxy.php` but also require one in `model.php:7` or `model.php:9` This leads to said fatal error. The solution would be renaming the Proxy class in `proxy.php`

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 2 issues with your OpenCart template.

1. `VERSION` constant is not defined. To check it, go to `index.php` and make sure it has a define for `VERSION` like `define ('VERSION', 'x.x.x.x');` (`x.x.x.x` should be the actual version of your OpenCart shop.
   It probably doesn't so you must add this definition.
2. Your template re-declares the `proxy` class. To prevent that, the easiest way is to check if it is defined already.
   In `/home/flower/mywebsite.com/system/engine/proxy.php`, wrap the class with `if (!class_exists('Proxy')){}`

This will check if the class doesn't exist before creating it again, and if it does, it won't create again and won't cause errors.

Note that it seems that your template isn't properly coded for the OpenCart version you have or supposed to be a template for a different OpenCart version, possibly an older version.